# Use shopify Price Rules api to create discounts in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shopify

I am developing an app for shopify app store in RoR and trying to use Shopify's new [PriceRules API](https://help.shopify.com/api/price-rules). But I am not able to make it work. I am using shopify-app gem and for price rules api I tries using:

```
ShopifyAPI::PriceRule

ShopifyAPI::PriceRules
```

but it throws following error :

```
uninitialized constant ShopifyAPI::PriceRule
```

Does anyone has any idea on how can I make it work in Ror?

Thanks.

Comment: using `bundle open shopify_api` opens a blank vi file. I tried to open other gems also but I see blank vi file every time.

I am not a pro Rails user so it would be very helpful if you can guide me on how can I make this API work myself.

Comment: @DavidLazar thanks for your help!! I opened the gem and checked that there were resources with names of API endpounts and I didn't find PriceRule resource there.

So I created PriceRule class under ShopifyAPI module in my app and it worked.

I want to accept your comment as answer. How can I do it?

Comment: I moved my comments to an answer for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a bundle open shopify_api and examine the resources. You probably won't find the new-ish PriceRules endpoint. So you have to make it yourself or wait if you want the official Shopify one.

If you are using RoR, then you almost certainly are using bundler. An alternative is to open the Shopify Gem shopify_api, and you'll see all the resources currently supported. If you wanted to add PriceRules endpoint, hack it into that gem.